# android web font different

Tags: android, html, css, fonts

i'm live in S.korea and my english is not good

I hope you understand my poor English skills.

my problem is this

***Unlike Android 6.0 or later versions, versions differ from version to version.***

this is CSS

```
    .box {
        width:100px;
    }

    p {
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: -webkit-box;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }

    .font1 {
        font-family: helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
    }

    .font2 {
        font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
```

this is my code

```
<div id="test">
    <div class="box">
        <p class="font1">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</p>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
        <p class="font2">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktuCs.jpg)

I know that android is no have helvetica font and android 6.0 verion default font  'Roboto' too.

Q1. font-family: helvetica Neue,sans-serif 
    - Why is there a 'sans', not a font, like 'sans-serif'?
    (picture top)

Q2. is that font Droid??

Q3. font-familiy : sans-serif; is wrong?? if i write just only this , font is serif style, but i need sans-serif font! TT.....

Sorry for Not English well. but i need ur help, beacuse i think S.korean people don't know this problem

Answer (score 0):

### Q1. font-family: helvetica Neue,sans-serif - Why is there a 'sans', not a font, like 'sans-serif'? (picture top)

Sans-Serif and Serif are two different categories of font, considering Times New Roman and Arial: Times New Roman is a commonly used serif font, where Arial is a commonly used sans-serif font. (Do I understand your question correctly?)

### Q2. is that font Droid??

Droid fonts are totally different fonts by Ascender Corporation. They do have Droid Sans or Droid Serif, but they are a different set of fonts designed for small screens.

### Q3. font-familiy : sans-serif; is wrong?? if i write just only this , font is serif style, but i need sans-serif font! TT.....

I think you spell it wrong.. try "family" but not "familiy". Otherwise you may be interested in this example:

```
jsfiddle.net/dsymbwwg
```

One more hint for communicating in English, try use Google Translate, you can type your question entirely in Korean and get the English result, paste that to us so that we could better understand your situation. :)

Hope that helps.